# Half black & white screen before app starts

Tags: android

My android app shows a half black & white screen before the splash screen. 
[image: half black & white screen]

I don't know what I do below is my splash layout xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.jarvis.easysplay.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/logo2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_26sdp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.574"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my splash activity class

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000;
//    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
   }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing with  private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000;?

Comment: its splash screen timer

Comment: I have just removed my code that start mainAcitivity after 5 seconds just for testing if this black screen show or not without that code, but it shows

Comment: Instead of the black screen, you want to show the ImageView with logo2?

Comment: Please make activity_splash as your launcher activity in manifest. If you haven't

Comment: Try removing ConstraintLayout use LinearLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your main theme

`<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`

`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>`

Comment: remove tools:context="com.jarvis.easysplay.SplashActivity" from your xml file    check your drawable folder and make shure that you have used "dp" for the text size

Comment: hey Thanks, @Pranav, when I run my app in other mobile it is working fine and now it is working fine in my mobile also. I don't know what the problem was??

Answer (score 0):

Try removing constraint layout and instead of that use Linear or Relative layout

Comment: I always use Constraint Layout and it's working great with Constraint Layout but suddenly I got this screen. I don't remember what I did.